# Unable to insert data on mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting error

> Undefined variable: company_name.

but some fields are inserted in database.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vdl");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
        $Company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
        $since = $_POST['since'];
        $strength = $_POST['strength'];
        $head_quarter = $_POST['head_quarter'];
        if($company_name !=''||$since !=''){
            mysqli_query($con,"insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('$company_name', '$since', '$strength', '$head_quarter')");
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do not use mysql but use mysqli or pdo.... mysql is outdated. Also use prepared statements, your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injections. So your if loop is returning a true which means it will execute everything in there. Seeing that your query doesn't insert but you get an echo saying data inserted succesfully means that your query is incorrect and its not functioning properly

Comment: Please, don't use the `mysql_*` functions. These functions are deprecated, and are removed in PHP 7. You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: You will get 'Data Inserted successfully' even if the `mysql_query()` call fails.

Comment: Thanks Tomm and Syscall...  i am new to php and my sql.so  i don't know how to use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? That you don't get the right message, when insertion failed? Or that the insertion failed? Or both? If any of the latter two please provide DDL of the table and the values of the variables you try to insert.

Comment: Because you are using Capitacal C for company name :)

Comment: You have to use $company_name instead of $Company_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and have been completely removed as of PHP 7.0.

Staying up to date with whats new and good now you reguarly want to update things aswell as PHP. Knowing that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (not under active development) we should not use them anymore (we can't even use them anymore if you have updated your php). Anyways back to the point you should not use `mysql_*` functions especially not now you are *new to programming* because you will have to update your php someday meaning you will have to change all of your code.

As of the code below:

This is `mysqli_*` [mysqli.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

I have added a check on the db connection checking if that is actually working since you did not check the connection. Because even without that connection working that if loop would still return you your echo.

In `mysqli_*` you also have to add the connection in the query string.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vd1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$since = $_POST['since'];
$strength = $_POST['strength'];
$head_quarter = $_POST['head_quarter'];
if($company_name !=''||$since !=''){

mysqli_query($con,"insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('$company_name', '$since', '$strength', '$head_quarter')");

mysqli_close($con);
}
}



?>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you've changed and why it solves the problem would be useful.

Comment: @NigelRen I always post my answer before adding explanation.

Comment: @Tomm After adding this code i am getting this error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: @karthikjoe you should try the above

Comment: @Tomm i have tried this but it doesn't show any errors and also data was not stored in mysql.

Comment: @karthikjoe what happends if you run this in sql itself `insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('1', '2', '3', '4')`

Comment: @Tomm 
 1 row inserted. [br] Inserted row id: 2 (Query took 0.0400 seconds.)
insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('1', '2', '3', '4')

Comment: @karthikjoe run this in php : `var_dump(mysqli_query($con,"insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('$company_name', '$since', '$strength', '$head_quarter')");)`

Comment: @Tomm pls see edited question..! sry unable to post long post in comments.

Comment: @karthikjoe you have a Capital C on your var company_name and on your query you dont have a Capital C

Comment: @karthikjoe glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

First of all mysql is deprecated. Don't use mysql. Use either mysqli or pdo.

In your given code,

Add condition after $query statement to get exact error.

```
if (!$query) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}
else {
   echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
```

Comment: connection is optional (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and will use the last opened connection if omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should trace all errors that may occur. I suggest to use **prepared statement**, try this:

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "vdl");
if($sql->connect_errno)
    return printf("MySQL Connection Error #%d: %s", $sql->connect_errno, $sql->connect_error);

// I'd recommend to not use $_POST['submit'], it'd be better to check all the fields (company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) using the strlen() function
// for example: if(strlen($company = $_POST["company_name"]) && strlen($since = $_POST["since"])) ... etc.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    if(!$sm = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `digital_library` (`company_name`, `since`, `strength`, `head_quarter`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
        return printf("Unable to prepare statement. Error #%d: %s", $sm->errno, $sm->error);

    if(!$sm->bind("ssss", $_POST["company_name"], $_POST["since"], $_POST["strength"], $_POST["head_quarter"]))
        return printf("Unable to bind parameters. Error #%d: %s", $sm->errno, $sm->error);

    if(!$sm->execute())
        return printf("MySQL Query Error #%d: %s", $sm->errno, $sm->error);

    printf("The query has successfully executed!");

} else
    printf("There's nothing to see, get outta here");

?>
```

If you don't want to use **prepared statement**, do this:

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "vdl");
if($sql->connect_errno)
    return printf("MySQL Connection Error #%d: %s", $sql->connect_errno, $sql->connect_error);

if(
    strlen( $company = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST["company_name"]) )
    && strlen( $since = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST["since"]) )
    && strlen( $strength = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST["strength"]) )
    && strlen( $head_quarter = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST["head_quarter"]) )
) {

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `digital_library` (`company_name`, `since`, `strength`, `head_quarter`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $company, $since, $strength, $head_quarter);

    if(!$q = $sql->query($query))
        return printf("MySQL Query Error #%d: %s", $sql->errno, $sql->error);

    printf("The query has successfully executed!");

} else
    printf("There's nothing to see, get outta here");

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing and It will be easy for you to debug-

**Change this**

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('$company_name', '$since', '$strength', '$head_quarter')");

echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
```

**to**

```
  echo "insert into digital_library(company_name, since, strength, head_quarter) values ('$company_name', '$since', '$strength', '$head_quarter')";
```

Now when you submit you get the original query in response.

Now run this query in phpmyadmin manually and see the results. Correct the issues phpmyadmin gives you and update your query in your script accordingly.